# Absolute positioning inside a div positioned in grid

Tags: css

I am trying out CSS grid layout and currently facing a problem. I would like to use `position: absolute` for a child of a div positioned in a grid. As you can see below (code snippet) the red box is set with `position: absolute` and is a child of `.left`.

How do I make it so that the red box visually stays in the orange div (left side) and doesn't "overflow" in the brown div (right side)?

I have tried setting `position: relative` to the parent element, without result.

Below is a simplified version showing the problem (you can modify the value to see the separator move)

```css
html,
body,
section {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.window {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "first seperator last";
  grid-template-columns: 100px 10px auto;
  /*                     | this one       */
}

.left {
  background: #ff9e2c;
  grid-area: first;
  position: relative;
}

.right {
  background: #b6701e;
  grid-area: last;
}

.separator {
  background: white;
}

.abs-pos {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 75px;
}
```

```html
<section class="window">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="abs-pos"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="separator"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</section>
```

The following is a GIF of the problem:
[image]
**PS:** In the actual file I have a JS script that allows me to move the `.separator` div horizontally to change the sizes of the two `div`s: `.left` and `.right`. It basically modìfies the property `grid-template-columns: 100px 10px auto` of `.window` therefore resizing the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `overflow: hidden;` on the `.left` pane will keep the red box from showing up outside its parent's bounds.

```css
html,
body,
section {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.window {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "first seperator last";
  grid-template-columns: 100px 10px auto;
  /*                     | this one       */
}

.left {
  background: #ff9e2c;
  grid-area: first;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.right {
  background: #b6701e;
  grid-area: last;
}

.separator {
  background: white;
}

.abs-pos {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 75px;
}
```

```html
<section class="window">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="abs-pos"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="separator"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you know why `overflow: hidden` doesn't work unless I have also `position: relative`?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think that's because the `position:absolute` causes it to flow up to a higher level than the `.left`  container. So since it's absolute and the left container isn't `position: relative` it positions itself based on `<body>` and thus doesn't get hidden.

Comment: Essentially the `position: relative` causes the `.left` pane to say to the red box, "position based on me, not anything higher". And only things positioned based on that element will be hidden.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications Don, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to give your classes a z-index

```
  z-index: -1;
```

Z index sets the stack order And works with positioned elements. I.e absolute, relative, fixed.

So if you can give your .right and or .seperator class a position relative it should work.

```
 .right {
     position:relative;
     z-index: 1;
}

 .separator {
     position:relative;
     z-index: 1;
 }

 .abs-pos {
     position:absolute;
     z-index: -1;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you Harry, I didn't know `z-index` would fix this.

Comment: The only problem with this is if you add a third section things get hairy, not part of this question but something to consider